# How to cancel back page button without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ajax

Following the client asking, I need to make a huge change in my research form.
Like Sarenza (http://www.sarenza.com/baskets-mode-homme), my form load in AJAX the content and display the products.

But the client, ask to make the same thing that Sarenza did: when you search for a product and press the back page button, only the results change, and no refresh/change in the page occurred.

I want to catch the back page/next page button whatever the way used to.

Is there a solution?
What is the best way to do that?
What solution use Sarenza?

Comment: Did you check that website's source code and JS to find out how they do it or not?

Comment: Use window.onbeforeunload to capture whenever a page try to exists

Comment: @N.B. the js is minified, but I think that they use backbone and window.history.pushState to store the history ..

Comment: @Dineshkani : the window.onbeforeunload can return false ? I don't think so ..

Comment: [Check this one out, it's probably what you need](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Comment: Then, following your link .. if I 'pushState' the history, you think that the browser history change, and when I click on back page button, the URL will be the one I pushed before ?

Comment: That's the introduction to the history API. It's what Backbone's router uses, and using hashbang URLs you can achieve what you described. Since I'm not in a position to study that website's form, I'm just pointing you to the mechanism used at that website, which is what comes with Backbone out of the box

Comment: Ok ok, thanks a lot for the link :). It seems to be what I looking for !